# Return a value from function after coroutine

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

i am writing an android contentprovider and the insert function calls a room insert operation. I am calling this operation from a coroutine, but i need the id returned in the coroutine to build a uri to return to the function caller.

```
    override fun insert(uri: Uri, values: ContentValues?): Uri? {
            ...
            val id: Long...
            GlobalScope.launch {
               id = dao.insert(entity)
            }

            //I NEED THE id so i can do following
            context.contentResolver.notifyChange(uri, null)
            return ContentUris.withAppendedId(uri, id)
           ...
    }
```

But what happens of course is that the function continues with id as 0. though the coroutine executes and inserts but i cant have the id.

Comment: You can't make a non-suspendable function return a value from a launched coroutine, unless you block until it's done. In which case you're right where you would have been without coroutines in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @MarkoTopolnik. How can i achieve same without coroutines. The only requirement is not to run the room operations on the main thread.

Comment: There is no way, with or without coroutines, to have `fun insert` return the value of `dao.insert` without blocking the main thread.

Comment: Thanks @MarkoTopolnik. So i have to allowMainThreadQueries on the database. but this is not recommended.

Comment: No, you must just give up the idea that you'll return the value from the function. Instead you must let all the logic downstream of that database query also happen asynchronously, within the coroutine you have launched.

Comment: Ok thanks @MarkoTopolnik. I will do so. Much appreciated